# Repeated Inline Copy+Paste in Notepad++ Defined by text in Document

Tags: list, notepad++

I'm trying to do something very specific - I want to copy a phrase from lines marked by '_grp_tag' and insert it into every line after the line marked '_grp_tag' until the next line marked '_grp_tag'. I also want to insert a number into those lines between the marked lines which represents the number of lines between the said marked lines.

Here's an example of what I start with:

```
Nippon_grp_tag;Nippon_grp;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Hikoru_tag;Hikoru;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Banyadai_tag;Banyadai;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Banmama_tag;Banmama;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Toshishi_tag;Toshishi;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Arab_grp_tag;Arab_grp;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Baldiahiti_tag;Baldiahiti;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Osanisataah_tag;Osanisataah;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
English_grp_tag;English_grp;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Kekenland_tag;Kekenland;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Datumbechester_tag;Datumbechester;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Briberham_tag;Briberham;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Kemershire_tag;Kemershire;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Sumerian_grp_tag;Sumerian_grp;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Suga_tag;Suga;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Numupak_tag;Numupak;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Dupak_tag;Dupak;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
```

And here's what I want it to turn into:

```
Nippon_grp_tag;Nippon_grp;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Hikoru_tag;Nippon4_Hikoru;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Banyadai_tag;Nippon4_Banyadai;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Banmama_tag;Nippon4_Banmama;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Toshishi_tag;Nippon4_Toshishi;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Arab_grp_tag;Arab_grp;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Baldiahiti_tag;Arab2_Baldiahiti;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Osanisataah_tag;Arab2_Osanisataah;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
English_grp_tag;English_grp;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Kekenland_tag;English4_Kekenland;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Datumbechester_tag;English4_Datumbechester;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Briberham_tag;English4_Briberham;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Kemershire_tag;English4_Kemershire;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Sumerian_grp_tag;Sumerian_grp;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Suga_tag;Sumerian3_Suga;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Numupak_tag;Sumerian3_Numupak;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
Dupak_tag;Sumerian3_Dupak;;;;;;;;;;;;;x
```

Although I would like to point out that it isn't absolutely necessary to have the numbers, so if that's impossible, I'm fine. Is there any way to do this in Notepad++?

Comment: I am not sure whether text editor is right tool for the job. The file is in CSV format, right? Could you use Excel instead? This would be easy there.

Comment: @miroxlav How would I go about doing it in Excel?

Comment: (1) Open file as CSV file in Excel. It should fit nicely into columns. (Make sure your that *list separator* in your *Regional Settings* control panel is set to `;` – if not, change it so.)  (2) Change values in cells by Excel formulas as you need. (3) Save the file (keep CSV format on saving).

Comment: @miroxlav I can't find "Regional Settings" anywhere. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Hi, as I wrote, it is Windows Control Panel. This is another [guide how to open CSV's in Excel](http://superuser.com/a/606274/287473) (the same process  I mentioned in point (1). If you will succeed, continue with steps (2) and (3).  **Important:** if you change list separator to `;`, your Excel formulas will use it as separator, too. So formula **`IF(A1<0,A2,A3)`** will become **`IF(A1<0;A2;A3)`**. If you want to keep `,` as separator, check CSV from your question whether it contains commas. If it does *not*, you can temporarily replace `;` for `,` and use Excel without changing list separ.